# multicolumn "pivot" table query for Laravel model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

after 2 days of looking on laravel docs and stackoverflow with no success I have to ask the question

I have 4 models so far and I am trying to get all related info in one go.

user model has relationship:

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Transaction' );
}
```

store model has relationship: :

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Transaction' );
}
```

product model has relationship: :

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Transaction' );
}
```

and finally transaction model has relationships:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\User' );
}
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Product' );
}
public function store() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Store' );
}
```

transaction table (looks like a pivot table):

```
transactions:
    id - integer
    user_id : integer
    product_id : integer
    store_id : integer
    ....... some additional columns containing transaction specific data.
```

I would like to get all transactions with referenced details for auth user

aka "$user->transactions" however with this i am getting only ids no data from related tables. I did try by joining but it looks messy and I think there is better way of getting this data well structured in laravel

the join looks like:

```
   $transactions = DB::table( 'transactions as t' )->where( 'user_id', Auth::id() )
    ->join( 'products', 'products.id', '=', 't.product_id' )
    ->join( 'stores', 'stores.id', '=', 't.store_id' )
    ->get( array( 't.id', 't.product_id', 'products.name as product_name', 't.store_id', 'stores.name as store_name' ) );
```

my objective is to get user object with all information about user including transactions and other details as one JSON response using as little queries as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to append the needed values from your relationships on the transaction. First add them as attributes on the Transaction model as follows:

```
public function getProductNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->product?$this->product->name:"";
    }

public function getStoreNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->store?$this->store->name:"";
    }
```

Now, you can append them to your transaction in the Transaction model like this:

```
protected $appends = ['product_name','store_name'];
```

And retrieve the transactions as usual like this:

```
Auth::user()->transactions;
```

Or append them to the transactions (after the first step) at run time like this:

```
Auth::user()->transactions()->setAppends(['product_name','store_name'])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to get an user object then you should query the user, not the transactions.

Since you have defined all the relationships you can leverage the query to Eloquent, no need to do it by hand.

```
User::whereId(Auth::user()->id)->with('transactions','transactions.product','transactions.store')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response I knew there was elegant way of doing it. 

I wonder if there is good way to format the response as there is plenty of not essential information in the returned object. (this object is to be "utilised by" the frontend).

Comment: I will try  [**league/fractal**](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) to clean the output